# CUDA on Linux - screen freezes

Tags: fedora, nvidia, performance, video

So I have Fedora 27 and I have installed the latest NVidia drivers on a laptop that has a Quadro M1000M.

I am trying out an intense CUDA process (xmrig).

But when it's running, the graphical screen is frozen. It responds very occasionally, very slowly. Text virtual consoles are fine.

I read that there is supposed to be a watchdog timer in the drivers to prevent this, but somehow it is not working.

What can I do to fix this?